# Why are badges sometimes not awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished) earlier. I was the only answer, it got 10+ votes, and it was accepted. I am pretty sure this is the requirement for the Enlightened badge. I have seen many awarded since so I am pretty sure the badge script is "running".

What's the deal? Am I missing something?

Comment: please leave this open so I can point other "why didn't I get so-and-so badge" users to it.

Comment: The information here is outdated. Better information is available in [How do "badges" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853) or [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Comment: Curious badge should be award to me but it didn't. facing same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably lost an Enlighted badge somewhere along the way. Typical reasons:

- Question was deleted;
- Answer was voted to less than 10 upvotes because of a downvote, someone changing an upvote or a rep recalc losing some people's votes; or
- OP changed accepted answer.

In those cases you don't lose your existing Enlighted badges. You simply won't be awarded another one until you have enough accepted answers that qualify.

Comment: Thanks... I really didn't know about this behavior. Good to know I guess.

Comment: Wow, that seems kind of buggy

Comment: SO took the decision to not remove badges, which is probably fair enough. The other cases are fairly marginal.

Answer (score 2):

The enlightened badge is only awarded if your answer was the **first** answer for this question. This is un-intuitive, and IMHO wrong, but is probably the cause for your bagelessness.

See the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135647/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow/940294#940294).

---

**April 11<sup>th</sup> 2010:** Looks like the behaviour has changed, <kbd>Enlightened</kbd> badges now seem to be given for any accepted answer with 10 up votes (even if it was not the first answer to be given).

Comment: Does the down-vote mean that this is not correct? If so where is my enlightened badge for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector/347478#347478

Comment: I believe you're correct, and I agree that being the first isn't that important. But they're only badges... The down-vote may have been because the OP said theirs was the only answer, so it must also have been the first.

Comment: Are you sure about your update. On SO I've got 12 accepted 10+ vote answers but only 9 Enlightened badges. Or are you saying that answers that reach 10 points and are accepted *now* get the badge. Have you got any evidence for this? (links to answers where this applies).

Comment: @ChrisF, I'm not sure but I do know that I have as many enlightened badges as I have accepted answers with >=10 up-votes and that some of those were not the first answers to be posted. Perhaps your account hasn't been recalculated and you'll get the badge later on.

Comment: Doesn't look like that such update took place.