# Why wasn't Tumbleweed badge awarded

Tags: discussion, support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278261/when-should-i-start-to-use-a-third-party-batch-email-system) which I believe according to the criteria

> Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

My answer currently has:

- Asked 27 days ago
- Viewed 21 times
- No Answers, No comments

I expect the reason that I have not received the badge because I have received one upvote on my question, but this is not in the criteria. Or is 21 times too many views?

Comment: Did someone add an answer and then delete it?

Comment: I guess that's a possibility...

Comment: Someone with 10k rep can probably tell.

Comment: No deleted answers.

Comment: Could be a deleted comment?

Comment: @Adam, that was my next thought, but I don't think (outside of direct db access) there's a way to check that.

Comment: Do you *really* want the tumbleweed badge more than once? :)

Comment: @Jonathan, if you mean this question, he won't get tumbleweed because of all the comments.

Comment: Look, Jesse Beder tried this earlier (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/why-cant-the-tumbleweed-badge-be-awarded-multiple-times/21297#21297) but to no avail. It's a rough time getting a Tumbleweed here on Meta now.

Comment: fwiw, it has an answer now

Comment: I've got a single-upvote unanswered, rarely-viewed question as well. The criteria doesn't say anything about votes, so either the description needs to be fixed or the criteria needs to be loosened to match the description. I don't think upvotes should play into this at all. All an upvote means is that it's a tumbleweed OTHER people would like to see answered as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a tumbleweed-badge on one question, and it did need some more time than a week. So be a little more patient, and it will be awarded.

Comment: His question is nearly a month old, so if its taking this long, the phrasing on the criteria should be updated to be more accurate. However, I suspect for some reason his question is not eligible, its just not clear to me why.

Comment: Maybe, though not mentioned in the description of the badge, but the upvote took it out of Tumbleweedness.

Comment: @Random, if that is the case, it is undocumented and I think that should be corrected (and I'm also inclined to disagree with the choice, but that's a different story/question).

Comment: Its not a bug, its an undocumented state!