# Is the Tumbleweed badge broken on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tumbleweed-badge

I have a question ([Debugging iPad Safari crash running Dromaeo JavaScript tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143469/debugging-ipad-safari-crash-running-dromaeo-javascript-tests)) that's gotten 0 votes, 0 comments and only 12 views since June 29.  I realize that not all questions get answers, but I wonder why I haven't received the Tumbleweed badge.  I did edit the question about two hours after I created it to add an update; maybe that affected the calculation.

**Update:** Looks like [Why can’t the tumbleweed badge be awarded multiple times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/why-cant-the-tumbleweed-badge-be-awarded-multiple-times) talks about this, but doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?user_id=22514). It is a one-time-only badge, so you won't get another one if you have yet another question that satisfies the requirements.

...though now I'm honestly a bit baffled, because it's pointing to that question anyway but stating that you earned Tumbleweed back in '09...

Comment: I guess I thought you could get Tumbleweed multiple times, like the opposite of Popular Question.

Comment: I thought so too. I was almost sure I'd seen someone with multiple Tumbleweeds, but I couldn't point one out so can't be sure.

Comment: Unless the original question no longer exists (deleted, migrated) or now has enough views/votes/answers so it doesn't qualify.

Comment: @ChrisF That would explain it. I'm noticing that Tumbleweed is very fickle, and it doesn't stay attached to the question that earned it the moment it stops satisfying the requirements. So it probably does just reassign itself like that. As long as it is a one-time badge, it should probably just stick with the original trigger.

Comment: @Grace - see my answer, more information that could easily fit in a comment.

Comment: Re my last comment - I meant *couldn't* easily fit in a comment. (Must proof-read comments before hitting "Add".)

Answer (score 2):

If the original question no longer exists (deleted, migrated) or now has enough views/votes/answers so it doesn't qualify, then the badge will be come "detatched". For example The question I got it for on SU no longer qualifies so I get

> mar 6 at 10:02 Reason is no longer available

when I view https://superuser.com/badges/38/tumbleweed?user_id=289

So it will get "reattached" the next time an answer qualifies, but the date might not update.