# Haven't received Tumbleweed badge for a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and 13 views (but with one vote to close)

Tags: support, tumbleweed-badge

I asked a question 2 weeks ago with [no votes, no answers, no comments, and 13 views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6639888/278), and I haven't received a Tumbleweed badge. Could that be because there is one vote to close the question?

Comment: Well, you can expect to receive too many views now...

Comment: Possibly, someone might have voted on your question and later revoked their vote.  Or an answer or comment may have been written and then deleted. (IIRC, you're not notified of answers/comments deleted before you see them)  It *does* seem to fit all tumbleweed criteria now...  I'm not sure that question on topic though, you might get better answers at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @John Asking questions about how Stack Overflow works and reporting potential problems is definitely fine here. [WebApps.SE] is for all the other web applications out there. :)

Comment: @Anna I think I may have been unclear. This meta question is fine here, but the original question on SO seems to me to be more fit for webapps then SO. :)

Comment: @John Ahhh, that makes sense. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You've already earned](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=278) the Tumbleweed badge once for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736747/google-calendar-iframe-width), and [it is not a badge that can earned twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/why-cant-the-tumbleweed-badge-be-awarded-multiple-times). The full requirements for badges are [documented in great detail here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> **Tumbleweed**
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Ask a question that receives no votes, no answers, no comments and [no more than 11-15](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32376/tumbleweed-how-many-views-is-low) views in its first week of existence

However, things get a little bit more complicated than that. The question you originally earned the badge for has since been deleted, but since badges do not get revoked, you still have the badge. In this case, you have just *re-earned* a badge that you already have. This is documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

> However, if the criteria for a badge no longer exist — e.g. the post it was awarded for is deleted — the next award of that badge is negated. When badges are awarded, the system checks to see how many you're supposed to have, and only awards new badges when the number of badges you're supposed to have is greater than the number of badges you have.
>
> As an example, suppose one of your answers received 10 up-votes, which caused you to earn the Nice Answer badge. After you have the badge, that same answer is down-voted to a score under 10. The Nice Answer badge is not revoked. However, the next time you have an answer that gets 10 up-votes, you will not earn an additional Nice Answer badge, because the system sees that you already have the number of Nice Answer badges that you should have.

Answer (score 3):

According to:

- [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)

> #### Tumbleweed
>
> - bronze; awarded once

and so you can only receive the badge one time but you have already been awarded the Tumbleweed badge:

- [Lea Cohen earned this badge 1 time](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=278)

for a different question.